# How can there be differences in what my Computer sends and what my Router receives?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, lan, tcpdump

Since this is my first question, please excuse me if I did anything wrong, I'm happy to learn :)

I have tried to solve this for about 3 months but couldn't get it to work. I think the fault is mine, but the only thing clear to me is that something is wrong. However I've run out of ideas where this could be.

tl;dr:
I'm having trouble with my desktop and router appearing to capture different traffic, without anything between those two. I have rewritten my scripts several times but couldn't get it to work.

Here is my context:
In my bachelor thesis I'm interested in middlebox behaviour.
For this I have a setup in which I have one Ubuntu Server machine set up as a router using dnsmasq and the isc-dhcp-server and another machine running Ubuntu Desktop connected to the Server machines subnet over ethernet.
To test the middleboxes, I'm calling every on of the Alexa top sites (for testing purposes either the top 10 or top 100) using Firefox + Selenium with each middlebox and once without anything between the Desktop and Server(Router). At the same time I'm logging the requested domains using tcpdump on the desktop and on the server. However for my question, the middleboxes are not really important, they're only illustrating why I'm doing this.

To illustrate my setup I made this diagram(I'm not allowed to post images since I don't have enough reputation):
[image]

The Desktop is looping through the Alexa List, whereas the server is in an infinite loop, until it receives a quit message from the Desktop.
In the Desktops script there are timeouts (I've experimented with timeouts between 3s and 60s) between each step. It cycles through the Alexa List with websites.
Tcpdumps are named according to the current domain+middlebox/plain.
Afterwards another python script is loading the tcpdumps, cycles through dns packets and creates a dictionary with IP:Domain mapping. Then it creates a dictionary with each domain from the Alexa list as a key and the value containing a set of subsequently called domains. This is done for traffic captured on the server and traffic captured on the Desktop, however they both use the Desktops DNS Dictionary.
Finally I have a Script comparing the generated Dictionaries.

To verify the differences between Desktop and Server for middleboxes, I compare the Plain pages as well. However there are always differences between the domains captured on the desktop and on the server. Usually between 2 and 5 subcalls per alexa domain differing (Those are subcalls I would expect other Alexa Domains to call. For example wikipedia.org is probably not calling facebook.com, but facebook.com itself probably is. Facebook showing up as a subcall of wikipedia is what irritates me). From my understanding this shouldn't be the case. In the beginning I was using the Python Library PyShark, but because those problems were appearing I thought using tcpdump directly might do the trick.
I tried setting bigger timeouts, I tried capturing all traffic in a single file and I tried rewriting every line of code I thought could be erroneous.
There has to be an error somewhere, but I can't seem to find it. I know there is always some package loss, but especially when connected directly through ethernet I can't imagine it being this high.
I expect unexpected behavior from the combination between selenium/firefox and tcpdump. Latency in startup/closing down of those may be an issue, but I don't think this could be longer than 60s. I also expect the Ubuntu Desktop to send auto update requests and other system services while I'm running the test, but first I don't think they're doing that many requests and second I have my iptables set up to only allow tcp requests from the user that starts the python script.

Thank you so much for taking the time.
If you have any ideas/remarks where I could have gone wrong, I'd be grateful to hear it. If you have further questions, please don't hesitate to ask.

**EDIT:***(Clarification about what I'm trying to achieve)*
*My hypothesis* is, that if I call a domain with my desktop computers browser and capture the network traffic on both the desktop and the router, both captures should contain the same packets.
If I have a middlebox which is blocking some of the domains and put it between the desktop computer and router, comparing the domains appearing in the captured traffic on the pc and on the router should yield exactly those domains, which the middlebox blocked.

*My Problem*:
Even without a middlebox, there is a difference in the captured traffic and I don't know where it is coming from.

Example (I made this one up, I'll post a real one once I'm back at uni):
*Expected behavior*:

> wikipedia.org: {*On PC but not on Router*: [], *On Router but not on PC*: []}
>   facebook.com: {*On PC but not on Router*: [], *On Router but not on PC*: []}

*Actual behavior*:

> wikipedia.org: {*On PC but not on Router*: [**facebook.com**], *On Router but not on PC*: []}
>   facebook.com: {*On PC but not on Router*: [], *On Router but not on PC*: []}

Comment: It's hard to understand precisely what you're doing or the problem you're having. Can you show examples of the different packet captures?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question.

Comment: It is not so clear what you want to achieve exactly in the first place, but you should be aware that requests may be cached or other system interactions may occur, so stacking several layers of indirection is not helpful. Maybe some Firefox extension is loading facebook.com? You should start out by maybe generating single requests by hand and then see if you get the result you expect.